# How do I generate labels in a Kubernetes YAML using the range in Go template?

Tags: kubernetes, go-templates

Given this YAML config, I need to create multiple labels based on the number of elements in the `labels` array.

```
 template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{name}}'
      labels:
        '{{range .labels}}' 
        key1: '{{.}}' 
        key2: '{{.}}'
        '{{end}}'
    spec:
```

Comment: What should the labels look like?  Is this in the context of a tool like [Helm](https://helm.sh)?  The quoting around the `range`...`end` loop looks odd (the file including the template markup will not be valid YAML) and I could readily see this causing problems.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze . I have edited the description. This might not be the right YAML example, but I just wanted to understand how goTemplate range would be used in an kubernetes YAML, if labels is an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you quote the `range` and `end` like this, you get empty pairs of quotes in your output, `''`.

Additionally, you probably want to template the keys and values of the labels since those are key value pairs. You could name them `key1-n` using the index of your loop, but I don't think that makes a lot of sense.

So I think it should look like this:

```
template:
  metadata:
    name: {{.name}}
    labels:
      {{- range $k,$v := .labels}}
      {{$k}}: "{{$v}}"
      {{- end}}
```

```bash
echo '{"name": "foo","labels": {"one": "1","two": "2"}}' | tpl -f kube.tpl
```

```yaml
template:
  metadata:
    name: foo
    labels:
      one: "1"
      two: "2"
```

I have https://github.com/bluebrown/go-template-cli for this but it would be the same for any tool that uses go-templates.

Comment: Hi @the-fool, Thanks for your reply. The source from which I would get the labels will return values like 'dev', 'staging', 'prod', 'dev env' etc.. The template would be created by a user. She would define the keys. `app1: '{{index .labels 0}}'`  - This can used, but the user should know the length/size of `labels`. Labels like 'dev env' cant be used as labels in Kubernetes too (another problem).

Comment: @maheshbaliga, dont you think that is a fragile approach? Its very easy to get the ordner wrong or forget to add one key or put one to many. It should be key value pairs. If the user doesnt want to use all of them they can look up the specifc value for a given key in the map, so they can still create their own labels and pick, if they choose. But at least your variables have names/identifiers insteat of being purely positional. `{{ index .labels "env" }}`